# Dynamic Array names based on index of foreach loop forEach((key) => { const temp[{ key }] }

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I'm trying to format some data I get from a JSON object. 
The object got a videosource : video.videodata 
 
and the resolutions in which the video is transcoded in : video.transcoded 

The data:

```
"video": [
  {
    "videodata": "https://example.com/link/to/firstTestvideo.mp4",
    "transcoded": [
      "-360",
      "-480"
    ]
  },
  {
    "videodata": "https://example.com/link/to/firstTestvideo.mp4",
    "transcoded": [
      "-360",
      "-480",
      "-720"
    ]
   }
],
```

I want to format the data to:

```
videos: [ //global
  video: [
    0: [ 
        {
         src: "https://example.com/link/to/firstTestvideo-360.mp4",
         resolution: "-360p",
        },
        {
         src: "https://example.com/link/to/firstTestvideo-480.mp4",
         resolution: "-480p",
        },
        {
         src: "https://example.com/link/to/firstTestvideo.mp4",
         resolution: "full",
        },
    ],
    1: [
        {
         src: "https://example.com/link/to/secondTestvideo-360.mp4",
         resolution: "-360p",
        },
        {
         src: "https://example.com/link/to/secondTestvideo-480.mp4",
         resolution: "-480p",
        },
        {
         src: "https://example.com/link/to/secondTestvideo-720.mp4",
         resolution: "-720",
        },
        {
         src: "https://example.com/link/to/secondTestvideo.mp4",
         resolution: "full",
        },
    ],
  ],
],
```

so far I got:

```
...
const filler = ajax.response;
Object.keys(filler.video).forEach((k) => {
  const temp = [];
  temp[{ k }] = []; // <-THIS DOES NOT WORK??
  this.videos[{ k }] = []; // this.videos is a global [].
  const item = filler.video[k];
  const sl = item.videodata.substring(0, item.videodata.length - 4);
  Object.keys(filler.acf.video[k].transcoded).forEach((x) => {
    temp[{ k }].push(
      {
        src: `${sl}${filler.video[k].transcoded[x]}.mp4`,
        resolution: filler.video[k].transcoded[x], 
      },
    );
  });
  Object.entries(temp).forEach((o) => { 
    this.videos[{ k }].push(o[1]);
  });
  });
});
```

any ideas how to create the "Subarrays" of videos?
Since there is a dynamic number of videos, I can't do video[0], video[1], etc. 

is there a better way to format the data then string concatination? 
Unfortunately I can not change the layout of the called JSON 

Any ideas much appreciated!!

Comment: I am confused by your desired result. What is the `video` in the `videos` array. You won't be able to use `videos.video`.

Comment: @MikeM No, it should be an array. This is because the Videoplayer I want to feed expects an array formated like this.

Comment: @76484 I'm hoping to be able to use videos.video[0][0], videos.video[0][1]. Is this stupid?^^

Comment: I don't think you need the inner Array. In other words, I think your lookup should be `videos[0][0]`.

Comment: For example: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/xcqf0rLv/

Comment: @76484 Oh cool, alright I'll try this! Really like the mapping function, looks way more elegant!

Answer (score 0):

just check this fiddle and change it:

```
 const fnl = []
    vidoes.forEach(index => fnl.push( ...index.transcoded.map(vd => ({
    src: index.videodata,
  resolution: vd + 'p'
    })))
```

[js fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/m14vLsb3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The explicit `0:`, `1:` things do not seem to add any benefit, so this does that with a simple array. The desired example access `videos.video[0][0]` works this way too, as shown at the end:

```js
const whatever = {
  "video": [{
      "videodata": "https://example.com/link/to/firstTestvideo.mp4",
      "transcoded": [
        "-360",
        "-480"
      ]
    },
    {
      "videodata": "https://example.com/link/to/firstTestvideo.mp4",
      "transcoded": [
        "-360",
        "-480",
        "-720"
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const videos = {
  video: whatever.video.map(item => [...item.transcoded, "full"].map(resolution => ({
    src: item.videodata,
    resolution
  })))
};
console.log("videos:");
console.log(videos);
console.log("---");
console.log("videos.video[0][0]:");
console.log(videos.video[0][0]);
```